# Cannot debug a multiple-project solution in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, debugging, monodevelop, archlinux

I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.12 on Arch Linux.

I have a solution containing to projects: the first is a class library and the second is a console application referencing the first.

When I'm debugging the console application, the debugger won't step-in to the library code.

When enabling "debug framework code", the debugger steps-in to the framework code but still not to my library.

I've tried both the soft debugger and gdb.

Comment: Same problem here on Mint 15.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference the class library project as a dll or as a project?
Because you need to reference it as a project of your solution to debug it.

Comment: I have referenced it as a project